# Reading serial data from a Com Port

Tags: java, serial-port, serial-communication

I saw that there are a lot of question with the serial i/o operation  so i decided to share a snippet of my code in which i read serial data from a serial port with the RXTX library.
This class read wait when there are data on the serial port and printed it.The class also save data in a String named data which can be obtained from another class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.comm.*;

public class SimpleRead implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {
static CommPortIdentifier portId;
static Enumeration portList;

InputStream inputStream;
SerialPort serialPort;
Thread readThread;
public static String data = "";
public static String getData() {

    return data;
}

public static void setData(String data) {
    SimpleRead.data = data;
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
             if (portId.getName().equals("COM1")) {
        //                if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/term/a")) {
                SimpleRead reader = new SimpleRead();
            }
        }
    }
}

public SimpleRead() {
    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
} catch (TooManyListenersException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    readThread = new Thread(this);
    readThread.start();
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e);}
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch(event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];
        String data1="";
        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                data1=data1+(String) numBytes;
            }
            setData(data1)
            System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        break;
    }
}
}
```

The code for readig   data from the serial port into another class

```
  SimpleRead simpleRead=new SimpleRead;
  String finalData="";
  simpleRead.run();
  finalData=simpleRead.getData()
```

Comment: [tag:serialization] is not for I/O over serial ports. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: You probably should first post a question, like "How do I ... using RXTX?", then post your solution as an answer to that.